# Which program can crop and resize images in a specific aspect ratio?

Tags: cropping, aspect-ratio, resize

I have a set of images, all of which have quite different resolutions from each other. I want to first crop them in the ratio 2:1 and then resize them to 1000x500 so that the image is not stretched or distorted in any way. I used different image resizer programs to do it but I am able to process only a few images at a time whose lengths are approximately equal. I want a software or a piece of PHP or Java code to process all of the images at once and crop them all in the ratio 2:1 in the center. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need this often.

Comment: Just to confirm: if you had a 4000x4000 image, you would want to first crop it to 4000x2000 (how do you choose where to crop - centre of the image?) and then resize that to 1000x500?

Comment: GraphicConverter can do all that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, Yes, you got it right. I mean exactly that.

Comment: This is a nice little programming project. Since you mention PHP and Java, why don't you just write your own piece of software?

Comment: https://github.com/gumlet/php-image-resize will do all that. Resize, crop, etc. There are many others, have you tried any?

Comment: The canonical answer to this is to use ImageMagick in a shell script (IM also has PHP and Java bindings, if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

PHP has the [imagecrop](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagecrop.php) and [imagescale](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagescale.php) functions, so it should be trivial to cobble together a loop to process a batch of files.